# Javascript unload event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe embedded into the page. Iframe have a button, when clicked opens up some part of iframe into a new window. Tried this in following way-

```
var w = window.open(url);
w.onload = function() {
    console.log('loaded');
    w.onunload =  function () {
        console.log('unloaded');
    }
}
```

But the onload event is never fired because of which onunload event is also not fired. Any solutions ?

Comment: @A.Wolff - Seems ambiguous but more likely the OP is looking for `onunload`, not `onload`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish `But the onload event is never fired` So that's part of the problem

Comment: @A.Wolff - Thanks. As shown in the link added event listener for load and unload events on window reference and it worked.